# How to compare two columns with a twist

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

We have two reports, which we want to compare by ID (fields: Reference & Transaction ID):

[image]

Column A to F are out freighting company's invoice starting how much they have charged out company

Column H-I are pulled from Google Analytics stating the amount we have charged to our clients .

Column D and H carry the same records ( just unsorted ) .

What I want to find out is for each record ( order H/D) the amount we have paid and the amount we were charged to work out profitability

Column D paired with column F is to be compared with column I , I hope I am making sense here .

The result should look like below

```
Reference   Transaction ID  Total Amount    Shipping
16672062468 16672062468      86.9            105
```

Comment: Please, pay more attention on formatting when you ask the question. This article may help: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

1. Try using [vlookup](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093318) function in J2:

   `=vlookup(H2, D:E, 3, 0)`
2. To convert values in column "Shipping" into numbers, try [regexextract](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098244) formula in K2:

   `=REGEXEXTRACT(I2,"\d+\.?\d+")*1`

These formulas are to be copied down.